# авторизация через OK - не получаю почту

Tags: php, oauth

Здравствуйте. Имею ссылку на получение данных

```
https://connect.ok.ru/oauth/authorize?
client_id=111111111&
scope=VALUABLE_ACCESS,GET_EMAIL&
response_type=code&
redirect_uri=https://sait.ru/registr/enter/?provider=odnoklassniki
```

При переходе нет никаких запросов для получения прав ,а просто окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а должно быть так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажимаю "вход", то получаю все данные, кроме почты. Я так понимаю, проблема в самой ссылке или конфигурации приложения. В чем я ошибся  ? Спасибо !

скрипт http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1674